# I am having a tough time making a title appear for my body

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a  title appear on the body of this page. Well for some reason the title doesn't show up when I use the center tag and I am can't figure out why. Can someone tell me what I is wrong with my center tag?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title><?php echo'giggity'?></title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php 
    $Title="The Title of my page";
    ?>
    <center><?php echo $Title;?></center>
    <?php
        $con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'username', 'password','Employees');
        if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
         echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }
        // $db = mysqli_select_db($con,'Employees');
        $sql = "select * from Employ";
        $query = mysqli_query($con,$sql);


        echo "<table border ='1' style='height:90%;width:90%; position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0;border:1px solid' BGCOLOR='00FF00'>
            <tr>
            <th>Firstname</th>
            <th>Lastname</th>
            <th>Meetings_Today</th>
            <th>Sales</th>
            <th>Comments</th>
            </tr>";

//now read and display the entire row of a table one by one looping through it.
//to loop we are using While condition here
 while( $row = mysqli_fetch_array($query) )
{
    echo "<tr><td>". $row['Firstname']. "</td>";
    echo "<td>". $row['Lastname']. "</td>";
    echo "<td>". $row['Meetings']. "</td>";
    echo "<td>". $row['Sales']. "</td>";
    echo "<td>". $row['Comments']. "</td></tr>";
}

        echo "</table>";
 mysqli_close($con);

?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @JohnConde what does `$Title="The Title of my page";` look like to you?

Comment: Enable error reporting and start debugging your stuff.

Comment: This `<?php $Title="The Title of my page";?><center><?php echo $Title;?></center>` worked perfectly fine for me. You sure your file is `.php` and not `.html`?

Comment: Is php enabled on your server?...

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your code. Something else is breaking this. Any CSS happening here by any chance?

Comment: no just html and php.

Comment: Can you tell us what, if anything, does show up? What makes you think the `<center>` tag is to blame for your woes?

Comment: I've removed my closevote. But, you should really describe the problem. I mean how in the world doesn't it appear ? Did you check the source code ? Is it, there ? If it's there, is the CSS right ? Are you even opening the right file ? Those are basic debugging skills you should know as a developer.

Comment: Is it because I am generating a html table from information on a database

Comment: Instead of doing `<center><?php echo $Title;?></center>` try `<div align="center"><?php echo $Title;?></div>` instead, see what that gives. @user3152011 You could also use CSS and assign an `id` to the div.

Comment: What happens if you add a `<br>` after your `</center>` - at least it would then stand by itself...

Comment: There is no css involved in this and I am opening the right file.

Comment: @user3152011 lolwut. I give up

Comment: I tried the div tag and it didn't work

Comment: I tried putting a <br> after </center> and it didn't work

Comment: there are no errors given of at all it is just not making the text

Comment: You need to leave space for the title - the table is at `top:0`! See my updated answer.

Comment: See Floris' updated answer below, it makes sense. @user3152011 You do have styles already in place causing this. It's called `inline (styling) CSS`

Comment: thanks floris! That fixed it

Answer (score 2):

The following code works fine for me (see http://www.floris.us/SO/title.php)

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title><?php echo'giggity'?></title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php 
    $Title="The Title of my page";
    ?>
    <center><?php echo $Title;?></center>
    </body>
    </html>
```

This is exactly the code you pasted (same spaces etc), but closing the body and html tags after printing the title.

I recommend you start from this, then add code "until it breaks".

OK - I added code myself. The way you lay out your table, it goes all the way to the top of the page, and therefore "sits on top" of the title. Change the `top` to something that leaves space for the title - or put the title inside the table…

Possible solution:

```
echo "<table border ='1' style='height:90%;width:90%; position: absolute; top: 50; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0;border:1px solid' BGCOLOR='00FF00'>
```

I put this to work in http://www.floris.us/SO/title2.php

Source code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title><?php echo'giggity'?></title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php 
    $Title="The Title of my page";
    ?>
    <center><?php echo $Title;?></center>
    <?php
        echo "<table border ='1' style='height:90%;width:90%; position: absolute; top: 50; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0;border:1px solid' BGCOLOR='00FF00'>
            <tr>
            <th>Firstname</th>
            <th>Lastname</th>
            <th>Meetings_Today</th>
            <th>Sales</th>
            <th>Comments</th>
            </tr>";

// replace db access with a single line of text:

    echo "<tr><td>". "John". "</td>";
    echo "<td>". "Smith". "</td>";
    echo "<td>". "Pocahontas". "</td>";
    echo "<td>". "Firewater". "</td>";
    echo "<td>". "English". "</td></tr>";

    echo "</table>";

?>
</body>
</html>
```